Why is FreeIPA HBAC rule not enforced for sudo
Using FreeIPA on RHEL 9, I have both sudo rules configured and an HBAC rule. The HBAC rules are there to disable all access to certain accounts on some machines. I can test those with, e.g.:
ipa hbactest --service=sudo-i --user=*user* --host *host*

As I would expect, that returns Access granted: False regardless of the choice of service or whether I use a short or fully-qualified hostname. Using ssh to connect to the host is blocked, as are attempts to log in with gnome, vnc etc - again matching my expectations. However, when sudo -u *user* -i is used on the host this just works regardless. There are sudo rules permitting the initial users (which aren't just root) to switch to the target user but I would have expected the HBAC rule to apply and the login to be blocked. On some other machines, the working sudo is wanted.
ipa hbacsvc-find does list services like sudo and sudo-i which would imply that sudo is supposed to support HBAC rules. At what stage is this supposed to be enforced? I would assume that pam_sss.so should be responsible for this. The pam configuration I have is the unchanged from RHEL 9.4 defaults and does include pam_sss.so for all of auth, account, password and session. Do I need to change the configuration somewhere for HBAC rules to apply to the sudo-i service? Or am I misunderstanding something?
I'm aware that I could specify host restrictions in the sudo rule but there are many of them and they apply to a mix of blocked and allowed accounts so this is not trivial.

Answering my own question here, the cause of the problem relates to sudo authenticating with the password of the source user rather than as the target user. The source user has permission to be on the machine in the HBAC rule so it passes. The solution is to set the targetpw sudo option. That appears to work in combination with !authenticate. It wouldn't help if authentication with the source user's password was wanted.
